# Fileformat for EC public/private keys?

Tags: file, format, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

If I wanted to store both a private and a public key in a single file, what would be the easiest format to use? Especially if I'm planning to use the BouncyCastle library for Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a theoretical point of view, the public key can be recomputed from the private key (computational cost for that is slightly lower than the cost for producing a single ECDSA signature, or doing half of ECDH, so it is fast). Therefore, conceptually, you only have to store the private key, and the standard format for that is [PKCS#8](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2130), which is supported by Java with `java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`. Moreover, the PKCS#8 format includes provisions for optionally encoding the public key along the private key in the same blob, so this really looks like what you are looking for.

The tricky thing, however, is to convince the cryptographic provider (e.g. BouncyCastle) to extract the public key as such and/or recompute it. Apparently, if you create a `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` from a PKCS#8-encoded EC private key which also contains the public key, BouncyCastle will be kind enough to internally keep a copy of the encoded public key and write it back if you decide to reencode the private key in PKCS#8 format. However, it does nothing else with it; it handles it as an opaque blob.

Hence you must recompute the public key. Wading through the JCE and BouncyCastle API and unimplemented bits, I found the following, which appears to work (JDK 1.6.0_24, BouncyCastle 1.46):

```
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEECPrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEECPublicKey;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECPublicKeySpec;

// Create the provider and an appropriate key factory.
Provider pp = new BouncyCastleProvider();
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC", pp);

// Decode the private key (read as a byte[] called 'buf').
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(buf);
PrivateKey sk = kf.generatePrivate(ks);

// Recompute public key.
JCEECPrivateKey priv = (JCEECPrivateKey)sk;
ECParameterSpec params = priv.getParameters();
ECPublicKeySpec pubKS = new ECPublicKeySpec(
    params.getG().multiply(priv.getD()), params);
PublicKey pk = kf.generatePublic(pubKS);

// To reencode the private key.
buf = kf.getKeySpec(sk, PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.class).getEncoded();
```

Conceptually, I should use `kf.getkeySpec()` with `org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECPrivateKeySpec` instead of ruthlessly casting the private key to the `JCEECPrivateKey` class, but the clean method appears not to be implemented yet in BouncyCastle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (BouncyCastle v1.47, using JDK 1.7.* but I assume JDK 1.6.* will be fine too):

```
// Recreate the private key.
final KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC", "BC");
final PKCS8EncodedKeySpec encPrivKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(rawPrivKey);
final PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(encPrivKeySpec);
final byte[] rawPrivKey = privKey.getEncoded();

// Recreate the public key.
final X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(rawPubKey);
final PublicKey pubKey = kf.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
final byte[] rawPubKey = pubKey.getEncoded();
```

where `rawPrivKey` and `rawPubKey` are arrays of byte type.
I suggest you encrypt the encoded private key with a block cipher (i.e. AES) otherwise the file is subject to be stolen and then you are indefinitely exposed.